# Draw backs of using Lock inside my action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an administration controller class, and the administration tasks require adding and deleting entities on the same action method call, so I am afraid that when more than one administrator access the same action method at the same time , some Add operations will be initiated from the  first transaction while other Add operation will be initiated from the second transaction. and this might cause the final result to inconsistence results . Since some Add & Delete operations will be initiated from TransactionOne while the other were initiated from transactionTwo.
For example I have an action method:-

```
[Authorize]
 public class SecurityRoleController : Controller
            {

    Repository repository = new Repository();
    //code goes here
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssignPermisionLevel2(ICollection<SecurityroleTypePermision> list, int id)
        {
            repository.DeleteSecurityroleTypePermisions(id);
            foreach (var c in list)
            {
                repository.InsertOrUpdateSecurityroleTypePermisions(c,User.Identity.Name);
            }
            repository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("AssignPermisionLevel", new { id = id });
        }
```

That call the following repertory method which perform addition and deletion operations for the same action method call:-

```
public void DeleteSecurityroleTypePermisions(int securityroleID)
{    
    var r = tms.SecurityroleTypePermisions.Where(a => a.SecurityRoleID == securityroleID);
    foreach (var c in r) {
        tms.SecurityroleTypePermisions.Remove(c);
    }

}
```

and also the following repository method:-

```
public void InsertOrUpdateSecurityroleTypePermisions(SecurityroleTypePermision role, string username)
{    
     var auditinfo = IntiateAdminAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "ASSIGN PERMISION").ID, tms.SecurityTaskTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "SECURITY ROLE").ID, username, tms.SecurityRoles.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.SecurityRoleID == role.SecurityRoleID).Name, tms.PermisionLevels.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.ID== role.PermisionLevelID).Name +  " --> " + tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.AssetTypeID == role.AssetTypeID).Name);
     tms.SecurityroleTypePermisions.Add(role);
     InsertOrUpdateAdminAudit(auditinfo);
}
```

So to avoid any unexpected results , I decided to include a lock inside my action method as follow:-

```
[Authorize]
    public class SecurityRoleController : Controller
    {

        Repository repository = new Repository();
public static object REQUEST_LOCK = new object();
//code goes here
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AssignPermisionLevel2(ICollection<SecurityroleTypePermision> list, int id)
        {
            lock (REQUEST_LOCK)
           {

                repository.DeleteSecurityroleTypePermisions(id);
                foreach (var c in list)
                {
                    repository.InsertOrUpdateSecurityroleTypePermisions(c, User.Identity.Name);
                }
                repository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("AssignPermisionLevel", new { id = id });
           }
        }
```

So can anyone advice if what I am doing is right way , and will having Lock inside my action method affects the performance or have drawbacks I am unaware of  ?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why you're deleting and then inserting a new record? Why not update the existing record? This would avoid the need for the lock in the first place, as the RDBMS will handle this automatically by locking the record to be updated while the update is in progress (in true relational semantics, an update is a delete then a re-add with new values--but I doubt actual RDBMS implementations do this specifically, but they must guarantee ATOMICity with regards to data manipulation).

In any event, yes, this could have a performance impact if you're expecting a very high number of users to concurrently access your site (I'm thinking on the order of thousands of requests per second—pure conjecture here). Essentially, you're turning what would otherwise be an asynchronous multi-threaded application into a synchronous single-threaded application at the point when this action method is called.

In other words, if there's to be any performance impact by this design, this action method will almost surely be the bottleneck.

The only way to know for certain about the performance impact is to perform a load- or stress-test of your website, especially in regards to thousands of (near) simultaneous requests to this method per second.

**UPDATE:** I see you have a method called `InsertOrUpdateSecurityroleTypePermission`. You should probably separate this method/stored procedure into two, one that inserts and one that updates. This way, as I stated earlier, you can totally avoid potential threading/ATOMICity issues.

**UPDATE 2:**
OK, I think I found the design decision that's causing the unnecessary complexity. You could, instead, design a Stored Procedure using transactions to handle the adding/deleting of the necessary records in the prescribed order to accomplish your task. This way, you're leveraging the DB to make sure that this all happens ATOMICally; and using transactions, you can `ROLLBACK` in the case something is invalid or isn't able to be completed (which your current code won't do) all the while, enabling you to get rid of the `lock` in your action method. Furthermore, you can still use EF—EF allows you to call stored procedures that you create in your DB. As far as concurrent users are concerned, using this approach, you'll still have a "last write wins" situation (e.g. sequential "access").

Comment: it is named InsertorUpdate , but as the code shows it always add record.

Comment: i can not just perform Edit operation instead of Delete/Add, because i am populating a relation-table with parent IDs. so first of all i am deleting all the records that have certain parent ID, then I am adding new records which might purely new records or they might already exists but have been just deleted ?. and in my case this action methods are accessed by system admin(where there might be 3 - 4 ) users only , so still there is a risk that they call the same action method with the same parameters at the same time, but at the end having a Lock will not cause a buttle neck? what do u think?

Comment: If it's only 3 or 4 users, I wouldn't worry about it--you won't see any performance hit. However, in general, this is not a good design. Basically, you're trying to do something that a RDBMS can already do for you--and it's only because the data model for your design is not quite right. I encourage you to think more about your design decisions and what you could do different to simplify your code. Good luck!

Comment: not a bad design ,,, i have three table (UserGroup, PermisionLevel, AssetType) and there is a single table that provide a relationship between these three tables by storing the IDS. so it contains info such as (User Group A has Read permission on the physical asset). and since Entitiy framework does not map relation tables so to be able to created new permission for an asseets i will first remove all the records that are inside the relation table that have the associated asset id and then i will repopulate the table with the new values,

Comment: otherwise i have to check if the record already exists in the relation table and according to this i will update the record ot i will create a new record...

Comment: and at the end , how we can design a scenario where a single http request will perform multiple edit operations or as in my case multiple add/delete . there should be a lock somewhere . even if i will replace all the Delete/Add with multiple edits, what if two users call the same action method at the same time , then the edits from the two requests might conflict , so the final result might be a combination of the two translations edits !! . what do u think?